# Is it possible to configure IE to allow XHR to `http://127.0.0.1 from` HTTPS?

Tags: javascript, http, https, xmlhttprequest

FF (62) and Chrome (69) consider `http://127.0.0.1` a *potentially trustworthy* URL. This behavior is described in [Certificates for localhost](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/) article, details are provided on [w3.org site](https://www.w3.org/TR/secure-contexts/#is-origin-trustworthy).

This allows to do XHR requests to `http://127.0.0.1` from within `HTTPS`. For example JS code on a resource `https://something-in-my-network.net` can do XHR to `http://127.0.0.1:8080` if there is a local service running.

But IE (11) prohibits these requests.

It is possible to configure IE to allow XHR to `http://127.0.0.1` from within `HTTPS`?

The following code can be used to reproduce the problem:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1:8080', true);
```

IE will immediately throw `Access denied` while other browsers will not.

Comment: Have you considered other alternatives like `postMessage()`? It will require loading the localhost site within an i/Frame, but it may be possible to open communication for IE.

Comment: As far as I can test, IE errors on attempt to load `http://127.0.0.1` in `iframe` if origin is `https`. Anyway, XHR is the preferred method.

Comment: That usually happens when you try to request a non safe content aka http from a https page. just open the page if you can in http and you should be able to load. if not somthing is wrong with your security settings. Somthing with trusted sources as far i remember. Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: @Sangoku, I deliberately want to access `http://127.0.0.1` from within `https` connection and according to the link I provided in the question, it should be possible. Accessing `http://127.0.0.1` from within `http` is not a problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just doing a normal XHR http request to localhost, it will create an error as a part of the [security zones](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2005/01/26/ie-security-zones/) feature. There is a way you can make this work, outside of the code. You have to add "http://client.cors-api.appspot.com" to your "Trusted sites" zone.

Comment: I don't see anything in the "security zones" link you provided that relates to my question. Also how adding "http://client.cors-api.appspot.com" to "Trusted sites" zone can help me? What is "http://client.cors-api.appspot.com" and how it relates to my question?